# Java code outOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

My program is supposed to evaluate the user input against the capital array. It looks like i keep getting error messages like this one:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 19
```

Any one can help?

```
package Capitol;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Capitol {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r\n"); 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int correctAnswer = 0;
        String [][] grid = {
                {"Alabama", "California", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia",
                "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Kansas", "Lousiana", "Maryland", "New Mexico", "Oregon",
                "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "Texas", "Utah", "Virgina",
                "West Virginia"},
                {"Montgomery", "Sacramento", "Dover", "Tallahassee", "Atlanta",
                "Honolulu", "Boise", "Topeka", "Baton Rouge", "Annapolis", "San Jose", "Salem",
                "Harrisburg", "Providence", "Columbia", "Austin", "Salt Lake City", "Richmond",
                "Charleston"}};

        for(int i = 0; i< grid.length; i++){
            System.out.println("What is the capital of ?");
            String capital = input.next();
            for(int k =0; k <20; k++ ){
                String answer = null;
                grid[i][k] = answer;


                if(capital.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)){
                correctAnswer ++;   
                System.out.println("Your answer is correct");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("The correct answer should be" + grid[i]);
            }

        }
        System.out.println("The correct count is " + correctAnswer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add the stacktrace you get.

Comment: In a 2d array you can get the length of the sub array for your nested for loop. Change `k <20` to `k <grid[i].length`

Answer (score 2):

you only have 19 items in your array row (0 to 18 index) and you are trying to work on 19th.

change

```
for(int k =0; k <20; k++ ){
```

to

```
for(int k =0; k <19; k++ ){
```

Comment: Maybe better: `for(int k =0; k < grid[i].length; k++ ){`

Answer (score 0):

In your subarray, particularly the first one, you only have 19 items in it. Because of the fact that array indices are zero-based, meaning they start at zero, your available indices for `k` are 0 - 18. When you attempted to use 19, you got an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which basically means that you were attempting to access an invalid index.

If you change the following line:

```
for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
```

to this:

```
for(int k = 0; k < grid[i].length; k++) {
```

it should solve your problem. The reason you should use `grid[i].length` instead of just a hardcoded number such as `19` is because that if you change the `grid` array, your code will adapt for you, and won't just ignore any entries after index 19. Whant the code, `grid[i].length` does, is gets the current subarray, and retrieves it's length. This means that even if the subarrays are different lengths, the `for` loop won't break. (Though why you would want subarrays with different sizes for this purpose is beyond me.)

Hope this helped.